# Instagram auth responds with 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: perl, api, oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to auth into the Instagram API, but my request fails on step 3: [Request the access_token](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

Note that there is no message in the response content. The error is simply, `Bad Request`.

Why won't my request go through?

note: my request is created and sent using the [Net::OAuth2](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emarkov/Net-OAuth2-0.62/lib/Net/OAuth2.pod) perl library.

#### request

```
'_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
'_content' => 'grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fredirecturi.net%3A4011%2Ffoo%2Fbar%2Ffoobar_callback&client_id=XXX&client_secret=YYY&code=ab1ef9ea901f401eb2ae798617e3b098',
'_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token')}, 'URI::https' ),
'_headers' => bless( {
    'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/6.05',
    'connection' => 'Keep-Alive',
    'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    '::std_case' => {
        'if-ssl-cert-subject' => 'If-SSL-Cert-Subject'
    },
    'authorization' => 'Basic XXX',
    'host' => 'api.instagram.com:443'
    }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
'_method' => 'POST',
'_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri'}
}, 'HTTP::Request' )
```

#### response

```
'_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
'_content' => '',
'_rc' => '400',
'_headers' => bless( {
    'connection' => 'close',
    'client-response-num' => 1,
    'date' => 'Thu, 07 Jan 2016 19:17:52 GMT',
    'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA',
    'client-ssl-cipher' => 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA',
    'client-peer' => '66.220.158.81:443',
    'content-length' => '0',
    '::std_case' => {
        'client-date' => 'Client-Date',
        'client-response-num' => 'Client-Response-Num',
        'client-ssl-cert-subject' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Subject',
        'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => 'Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer',
        'client-ssl-cipher' => 'Client-SSL-Cipher',
        'client-peer' => 'Client-Peer',
        'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'Client-SSL-Socket-Class'
    },
    'client-date' => 'Thu, 07 Jan 2016 19:17:52 GMT',
    'content-type' => 'text/plain',
    'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '/C=US/ST=CA/L=Menlo Park/O=Instagram LLC/CN=*.instagram.com',
    'server' => 'proxygen',
    'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL'
}, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
'_msg' => 'Bad Request',
}, 'HTTP::Response' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already solve it?

Anyway, I had the same issue recently (using C# but the problem principle looks like the same), so this answer it will be for those who will need a direction. There are important things to consider that isn't so clear on Instagram Developer Documentation.

On step 3 you won't pass the auth parameters through URL, you need to pass it as a body content (literally).

Other common issue is the header parameters, these must be:

```
Accept: "application/json"
ContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

I hope this answer will save time for other developers.

Other references: [Here](http://blog.humphriesj.com/2013/12/instagram-api-authentication-you-must.html) and [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/Dvu_4SXTDG4).